# Object Prototype toString Call - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I created a function that removes an object property + value if its value is an array. Here's how it looks like:

```
function removeArrayValues(obj) {
  for(var key in obj){
    if( Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) === '[object Array]' ) {
     delete obj[key];
     }
  }
}
```

Notice this part:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key])
```

I got this from a friend's solution however it's not clear to me what is it really doing. Also instead of just `'Array'` why do we need to put it within `[]` and call it `[object Array]`.

ALSO is there a better way to do this other than this solution???

I am an absolute beginner to JavaScript.

Can anyone teach me or discuss to me in layman's term what this code does?

Anyone?

Answer (score 11):

In javascript, each built-in type has its own `toString` method. For an array, that would return all of the array values joined with a comma, eg:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr.toString() // returns "1,2,3,4,5"
```

The `toString` function for Object (the built-in type for objects) happens to return what type of object it is as a string with the format [object Type]. So for example:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) // returns "[object Array]"

const str = 'test'
str.toString() // returns 'test'
Object.prototype.toString.call(str) // returns "[object String]"
```

So if you want to know if it's an array, that's one way to find out. The `toString` method resides on Object's prototype. `call` is a function that lets you change the context of another function. When you call `[].toString()` it will run the `toString` method on the Array.prototype. If you want the behavior of `Object.prototype.toString` (ie [object Type]) then you can use that function and call it with an array as the value instead of an object.

A better way, if you don't care about IE 8, is to use `Array.isArray`. For example, in your function:

```
function removeArrayValues(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) delete obj[key]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the best explanation. I do not understand the number of downvoted questions. For what reason has this answer been downvoted?

Comment: Some user came through and downvoted everything for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key])` actually returns a string `[object Array]` so comparing it to `Array` would not return a match

`typeof` can give you false if you're checking an array you got from an `<iframe>` hence this way of confirming the type is more reliable.

There is a great article on the subject here: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/